# NSSlider with non-linear scale

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, nsslider

I'm trying to make an NSSlider's values/digits non-linear...

```
@IBOutlet private weak var _countSlider:NSSlider!;

let countSliderValues:[Int] = [1, 20, 50, 100, 500, 1000];
_countSlider.numberOfTickMarks = countSliderValues.count;
_countSlider.minValue = Double(countSliderValues[0]);
_countSlider.maxValue = Double(countSliderValues[countSliderValues.count - 1]);
_countSlider.allowsTickMarkValuesOnly = true;
_countSlider.integerValue = 100;
```

But for some reason the slider is showing linear values (1, 200, 400, 600, 800, 1000). Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Because you never set the slider values, only the min and max values...?

Comment: You know what? You are totally right! How can the NSSlider know what values to deal with?! The question is: how do I tell it the values? It's not possible in IB either (only min. and max.). I've wrote this code from an example at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810753/how-can-nsslider-be-customised-to-provide-a-non-linear-scale-in-cocoa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of tick marks property sets tick marks that are evenly divided between the slider's min and max. There's no way to define a target value for each individual tick mark.

Your best bet is to roll your own solution by either subclassing `NSSlider` and `NSSliderCell` and coercing them to behave the way you want, or to create your own entirely novel control from scratch, specific to non-linear scaling. Nothing saying you can't still use `NSSliderCell` to draw the standard system parts (the track and the knob).

Comment: Yep: Nope. ;-) You'll have to roll your own solution that allows you to set individual values for each tick. Might be easier to build from scratch rather than trying to subclass NSSlider/NSSliderCell and bend it to your will.

Comment: @BadmintonCat its not clear if you want the scale to be log or if you want the tick marks to be positioned in log.

Comment: @Schemetrical Good point. Also not possible to position the ticks individually but if you just want the *value*, BadmintonCat can use an `NSValueTransformer` to transform "stop number" to "scale factor".